# Is plt.scatter() a redundant function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, scatter

I tried to find something I can only do with plt.scatter, that plt.plot can't, but with the use of the Line2D args and everything else it seems to me plt.scatter is basically useless. I came across this quandary after I tried to write a script for automated plotting with some user specified preferences. At first it seemed as if I would have to use both plot() and scatter() with an if condition, if the user wants only a marker, only lines or both. But that isn't necessary at all. I know this is sort of an open ended question, but shouldn't scatter be considered a deprecated function at this point? All it does is having a different default plotting mode. It I don't want a line, I can just set linewidth=0, right?

Answer (score 3):

#### Yes

If you want a set of ***single-sized***, ***single-colored*** markers, yes, you can use `plt.plot(x,y, linestyle="none")` instead of `plt.scatter(x,y)`. `plt.plot` is also a bit more efficient in such a case.

#### No

However, if you want to ***encode information into the size or the color*** of a set of markers, you will want to use `plt.scatter(x, y, s=sizes, c=colors)`. For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x, y, c, s = np.random.rand(4, 40)
s = s * 100 + 5

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sc = ax.scatter(x, y, s=s, c=c)
fig.colorbar(sc)

ax.legend(*sc.legend_elements("sizes"), loc="upper left")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: So the big difference is that color and sizes can be containers in scatter but only a single value for all datapoints in plot. Thank you. But wouldn't it be quite simple to add the functionalities of scatter to plot and make them one function? I feel this could be very convenient in a lot of cases...

Comment: No, it's not simple; already now `plot` as well as `scatter` are quite complex internally. But the main reason they are separate is that they create totally different objects; and it actually makes sense to have them create different objects because drawing a line should be much more efficient.